# python time data does not match format with identical mapping

Tags: python, date, date-format, strptime

I'm getting the following error:

> time data '2017-12-11 10:00:00' does not match format 'Y-m-d H:M:S'

The formatting looks perfect to me.

Here is my code:

start_date = '2017-12-11 10:00:00-08:00'
start_date = pytz.timezone(event.time_zone).localize(datetime.strptime(start_date[:-6],'Y-m-d H:M:S'))

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing `%` signs in the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prepend date placeholders with `%` in your casce it should be `datetime.strptime(start_date[:-6],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`